# Convergence of: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{2^{n}\sin^{2n}{\left(x\right)}}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I solved that it converges absolutely on $\bigcup \left(-\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\right) \text{for all k belongs to integer numbers}$
I don't know how to deal with "non-absolute" convergence.I think I can't use alternating series test becuase of non-decreasing character of sequence.Any hints?

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{2^{n}\sin^{2n}{\left(x\right)}}{n}}$$

Comment: The numerator is $2^n \sin^{2n} x = (2 \sin^2 x)^n$, so if at a given $x$ we have $2 \sin^2 x < 1$...

Comment: @Travis but it gives convergence on the same intervals like absolute convergence, plus it gives convergence on k*pi/4 but how i prove convergence/divergence for other parameters x?

Comment: Consider $f(y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2)^n}ny^n$. Then your term is $f(\sin^2(x))$. For $y=1/2$ you can use Leibniz. For $y=-1/2$ the answer is obvious.

Comment: At $\frac{\pi}{2} \left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)$, the sum is $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, which converges (by the A.S.T.) but only conditionally (taking the absolute value of the summand gives the harmonic series). Elsewhere, the summands don't even converge to zero, hence the series cannot converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** For fixed $x$, the series is
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{r^n}{n} ,$$
where $r := 2 \sin^2 x$. Show that this converges absolutely for $r < 1$, converges conditionally for $r = 1$, and diverges for $r > 1$.

> **Additional hints** Respectively: Compare with a geometric series with ratio $r$; use the Alternating Series Test; show that the summand diverges as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Why do you just repeat the same hint that I already wrote in the comments?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the complaint: I gave essentially the same hint in the comments---albeit a little less explicitly---~50 minutes *before* you posted your own comment, no? OP then directed to me a follow-up question, and I replied (again in the comments), but by that point all my comments comprised an answer anyway, so I rewrote my them as this answer.

Comment: I only saw your first comment (which is is not only "a little less explicit", but not at all helpful). And your second comment is below mine (which coincides with your answer).

Comment: Perhaps my original hint could have been worded more effectively, but "not at all helpful" is a subjective judgment, and certainly not a constructive one. My original comment contained the key observation that one can write $r = 2 \sin^2 x$ and hence write the numerator as $r^n$ and, by implication write the series as $\sum (-1)^n \frac{r^n}{n}$, which is perhaps easier to see how to handle.

Comment: I do not begrudge you for writing a comment that writes out the same observation but filling in more details---after all, after OP posted their comment it was clear they would benefit from seeing more detail. It's bizarre, though, that you did so and then accused me of repeating *you*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2)^n}ny^n$. By the formula of Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence is $r=1/2$. So, your series converges absolutely whenever $\sin^2(x) < 1/2$, and thats exactly for $x$ in the set you provide in your question. We also know from the theory of power series that the series does not converge for $|y|>1/2$, hence it remains to consider the case where $y = \sin^2(x)= 1/2$. In this case, the series converges by the Leibniz criterion.